# c++ how to remove objects from a vector in a function

Tags: c++, object, vector, reference

I would like to remove objects from a vector. The vector is passed by reference, and I'm lost. I have tried brickList.erase(it) and also the combination erase remove, but I can't figure out the correct expression.

Would someone be so kind to help me on the commented line? In the general case with let's say 100 bricks with random positions.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Brick {
private:
    int position;
public:
    Brick(int);
    int getPosition();
};
Brick::Brick(int p) : position(p) {};
int Brick::getPosition() { return position; }

void removeBricks(int a, int b, std::vector<Brick> &brickList) {
    std::vector<Brick>::iterator it;
    for (it = brickList.begin(); it != brickList.end(); ++it) {
        int currentPos = (*it).getPosition();
        if (currentPos >= a && currentPos <= b) {
            // here I need help to delete objects
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Brick> myBricks;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
        Brick tmp_brick(i);
        myBricks.push_back(tmp_brick);
    }
    // delete all bricks with position between 3 and 5
    removeBricks(3, 5, myBricks);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `brickList.erase(it);` it the immediate fix, although you don't really need a loop since you can delete a range if you use 2 iterators.

Comment: I tried brickList.erase(it) but I get an error: vector iterator is not incrementable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code

```
// delete all bricks with position between 3 and 5
//removeBricks(3, 5, myBricks);  // <-- replace this
myBricks.erase(myBricks.begin()+3,myBricks.begin()+5); // <--  with this
```

using the range based `erase` function. You don't need your `removeBricks` function at all really.

If you **have** to use `removeBricks()` function you could do it like this using the same function prototype.

```
void removeBricks(int a, int b, std::vector<Brick> &brickList) {
    // check a >= 0, a < b and b doesn't exceed length of brickList
    brickList.erase(brickList.begin()+a,brickList.begin()+b);
}
```

EDIT: seems that your notion of position does not refer to the array position of your items but the value of the member function of `Brick`. This should work for you.

```
void removeBricks(int a, int b, std::vector<Brick> &brickList) 
{
    std::vector<Brick>::iterator it;
    for (it = brickList.begin(); it != brickList.end(); /* DONT increment here*/) {
        int currentPos = (*it).getPosition();
        if (currentPos >= a && currentPos <= b) {
            // store the return value from erase!!
            it = erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            // increment here rather than in the for loop incrementer
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to store the return value from `erase` because the iterator gets invalidated. The above should work for you although vector is not the best choice of container as erasing items can be slow due to the restructuring of the underlying array.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I do if I have 100 bricks with random position? I need to check each brick and delete it if its position is between 3 and 5.

Comment: @user3019338 I see  - position is a problematic word in this context as it implies that you mean the position in the vector, not the return value of a member function. Does my updated answer work for you? As a comment suggest, vector is probably not the best container for this if you need to do a lot of item removal.

Comment: Yes!! Sorry for my wrong vocabulary, and thank you for your answer. :)